# iPhone YouTube Channel App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube

What would the steps be to creating an app that connected to YouTube's XML API.
Here is my setup currently but it is not working.

1. App Delegate creates object "YTXMLParser"
2. App Delegate calls [parser prepAndPrase];
3. In Prep and Parse the app initiates a NSURLConnection
4. The app downloads the XML Data using the NSURLConnection well appeneding to NSMutableData
5. The app parses the data with NSXMLParser
6. At the end of each "entry" the app adds the current dictionary to the array.
7. At the beginning of each "entry" the app creates an instance of a dictionary.
   **Here's where i'm stuck. How do I get this data back to my app delegate?**

Answer (score 1):

You should create a delegate (say, `YTXMLParserDelegate`) that has the method `- (void)doneParsingYoutubeData:(NSDictionary *)data`. You would have an instance variable `id<YTXMLParserDelegate> delegate` in your `YTXMLParser` and make it a `@property`.

In your app delegate, you would declare that it conforms to `YTXMLParserDelegate` by putting `YTXMLParserDelegate` in the angled brackets and then you would assign it to the `delegate` property (`parser.delegate = self`). You would also implement a method to do something with the data in your app delegate.

Finally, in your `YTXMLParser` class, after you receive the data, you would check that the `delegate` variable has the method implemented, and then call it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps a lot but I am wondering if I should send the whole array back or just a single dictionary.

Comment: Oops, yes, you should pass in the array. Another thing you could do is model your delegate after, say, `UIAlertViewDelegate`, where you pass back the entire `YTXMLParser` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the id of the AppDelegate to you YTXMLParser, then call the following to send the result back.

```
//In your YTXMLParser class .h file
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

//In the .m file
- (void)sendMethodToAppDelegate {//Call this after creating the dictionary
    [self.delegate sendToAppDelegate:MyDictionary];//or whatever the name is
}

//In your app delegate .h file
- (void)sendToAppDelegate:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

//In the .m file
- (void)sendToAppDelegate:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    //Do something
}
```